# Variance problem

Tags: statistics, variance

So I know how to calculate variance, but I ran into a peculiar problem. If I roll a dice until I get a 5 or 6, what would the variance of this distribution be? I've also been told the answer is 6 but I have no idea how to start this problem.

Comment: What's the random variable? The number on the die, or the number of rolls it takes to get a 5 or a 6? Or something else? If it's the first of these, then the mean is $5.5$ and the variance is $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let random variable $X$ be the number of **trials** (tosses) until we get a $5$ or a $6$. Then $X$ has *geometric distribution* with parameter $p=\frac{1}{3}$. (Here $p$ is the probability of "success" on any one trial.)

The variance of a geometric distribution with parameter $p$ is $\frac{1-p}{p^2}$. When $p=\frac{1}{3}$, the variance of $X$ is indeed $6$.